# Unable to maintain responsive behavior on a full height page with vert/horz centered content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am building a fullheight site where i need the first section to have vertical and horizontal centered content. Unfortunately there is a image as a part of the deal, which is not able to scale resopnesive when the screen size is altered. How do i deal with this issue as it seems like the transform method solved the centering challenge to begin with. On the top of the first section i have a header which has to be taken into considerations with the solution.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yevr2tLm/1/

**HTML**

```
<section class="container-fluid">
  <header>This is a header</header>
  <div class="content__1">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" />
    <p>
      This is some awesome text
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content__1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

header {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: So what do you want to happen?

Comment: I like the result, but the image is not responsive in this setup.

Comment: In what way? Seems to be in the example you provided

Comment: Try to resize the screen. The image is not really following the resolution

Comment: The image is responsive? it is a proportion of the screen width

Comment: @JavaCake - Do you mean when you change the screen width or height? Currently the width of the image *is* responsive which is generally how responsive design works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with **Flexbox**. If you use `flex-direction: column` on container element now you have two flex-items: header and content one below another. So what you can do now is use `flex: 1` on content so it will take rest of window height that is left after `header` and you get something like this

[image]

Now you need to vertically and horizontally center content inside `content__1` element and you can do this if you use `display: flex` on `content__1` also and then you just add `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`. And to keep `img` responsive you can use something like `width: 60%` and `height: auto` but you can adjust that depending on image size.

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container-fluid.flex,
.content__1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container-fluid.flex {
  height: 100vh;
}
.content__1 {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}
header {
  background: black;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
img {
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 70%;
  height: auto;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid flex">
  <header>This is a header</header>
  <div class="content__1">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" />
    <p>This is some awesome text</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can do this with **CSS Tables**. Lets say `header` has `height: 50px` now you can use `height: calc(100vh - 50px)` on content element with `display: table`. Now you just need to center content inside table and you can do that if you wrap content inside another div that will have `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` properties

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container-fluid.flex {
  height: 100vh;
}
header {
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.content__1 {
  display: table;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 70%;
  height: auto;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid flex">
  <header>This is a header</header>
  <div class="content__1">
    <div class="inner">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg" />
      <p>This is some awesome text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do the following:

```
<style>
    body,
    html {
        background-image: url('http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE1LzA5LzEzLzNjL2dvb2dsZXRodW1iLmIyNGE0LmpwZwpwCXRodW1iCTk1MHg1MzQjCmUJanBn/63126c72/af4/google-thumb.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 80%;
        background-position: center;
        height: 100%;
    }

    section {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .content__1 {

    }

    header {
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 2em;
    }
</style>
```

The body then becomes:

```
<body>
    <section class="container-fluid">
        <header>This is a header</header>
        <div class="content__1">
            <p>
                This is some awesome text
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont like how small image gets when resizing put min-width:300px or the pixels you want to image.